# Android, writing on specific sectors

Tags: java, android, memory, erase, sector

I wonder if there's a possibility to create an android app in java which will be installed on specific memory sectors of phone(not the sd card). So those sectors can be accessed from other app and it can be completely erased(couple times write/erase so it won't be recovarable). Do you have any ideas?
Best Regards,
Martin

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly then I think what you want is not possible.

All downloaded apps are instaleld to `/data/app/` or SD card. There is no way to put them anywhere else under normal circumstances.

What you can do however is make MODE_WORLD_ WRITABLE files from within your application. If you do that then other applications will be able to see and manipulate those specific files.